# Simple Pinger batch-script with "Working" and "Not Working" results runs infinitely without internet

Tags: batch-file

I made a simple batch script to ping 8.8.8.8 a few times before returning either a positive or a negative message box. When the internet is working, it goes fine. But when it isn't, the script pings infinitely without generating a message box. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?
Also, if the script looks extremely rudimentary, it's because it probably is. I'm a newb at this.

```
@echo off

:PING
ping 8.8.8.8
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 goto GOODCHECKER
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto BADCHECKER

:GOODCHECKER
ping 8.8.8.8
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (ping 8.8.8.8)
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto BADCHECKER
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (ping 8.8.8.8)
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto BADCHECKER
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (ping 8.8.8.8)
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto BADCHECKER
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 goto GOOD
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto BADCHECKER

:BADCHECKER
ping 8.8.8.8
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ping 8.8.8.8)
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 goto GOODCHECKER
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ping 8.8.8.8)
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 goto GOODCHECKER
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto BAD
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 goto GOODCHECKER

:GOOD
echo set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > %tmp%\tmp.vbs
echo WScript.Quit (WshShell.Popup( "The internet is working at the moment. You can close out of the console window now, or let it run a little longer to be absolutely sure." ,10 ,":)", 0)) >> %tmp%\tmp.vbs
cscript /nologo %tmp%\tmp.vbs
goto PING

:BAD
echo set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > %tmp%\tmp.vbs
echo WScript.Quit (WshShell.Popup( "The internet is not working at the moment." ,5 ,":(", 0)) >> %tmp%\tmp.vbs
cscript /nologo %tmp%\tmp.vbs
goto PING
```

EDIT:

Ended up completely reworking the script based on further research. Works as intended now.
Here it is for anyone interested:

```
@echo off

TITLE = Pinger

:INITIAL
echo Please wait while I check your connection.
ping 8.8.8.8 | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms" > nul
if %errorlevel% == 0 (goto GOODCHECKER) ELSE (goto BADCHECKER)

:GOODCHECKER
ping 8.8.8.8 | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms" > nul
if %errorlevel% == 0 (ping 8.8.8.8 | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms" > nul) ELSE goto BADCHECKER
echo Still checking.
if %errorlevel% == 0 (ping 8.8.8.8 | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms" > nul) ELSE goto BADCHECKER
if %errorlevel% == 0 (ping 8.8.8.8 | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms" > nul) ELSE goto BADCHECKER
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto GOOD

:BADCHECKER
ping 8.8.8.8 | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms" > nul
if %errorlevel% == 1 (ping 8.8.8.8 | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms" > nul) ELSE goto GOODCHECKER
echo Still checking.
if %errorlevel% == 1 (ping 8.8.8.8 | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms" > nul) ELSE goto GOODCHECKER
if %errorlevel% == 1 (ping 8.8.8.8 | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms" > nul) ELSE goto GOODCHECKER
if %errorlevel% == 1 goto BAD

:GOOD
color 2F
echo The internet is working! :)
echo set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > %tmp%\tmp.vbs
echo WScript.Quit (WshShell.Popup( "The internet is working. You can close out of the green window now, or hit OK to have me check again." ,30 ,":)", 0)) >> %tmp%\tmp.vbs
cscript /nologo %tmp%\tmp.vbs
echo I'll check again.
goto GOODCHECKER

:BAD
color 4F
echo The internet is not working :(
echo set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > %tmp%\tmp.vbs
echo WScript.Quit (WshShell.Popup( "The internet is not working at the moment. You can close out of the red window now, or hit OK to have me check again." ,20 ,":(", 0)) >> %tmp%\tmp.vbs
cscript /nologo %tmp%\tmp.vbs
echo Alright, I'll check again.
goto BADCHECKER
```

Comment: What's the name of your batch file ?

Comment: Uhm. "pinger - Copy.bat". Why?

Comment: If you constantly run it, google will block your icmp traffic. If you intend to use icmp for testing internet connectivity, you should consider pinging perimeter or edge router. In general, ping flood is not a good solution to check for connectivity. In perspective, if your sink is clogged, do you pour more water to test if it is clogged? Or on traffic, will it be a good idea to send more car to a clogged street to see if the street will clear out?

Comment: How do I ping perimeter or edge router?

Comment: `errorlevel` of `ping` is not reliable. Better use `ping .... |find "TTL="`  instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your :BAD tag goes back to the PING tag after you've notified the user that the internet is not working. Just remove that last **goto PING** statement.

Here's a different version of your script that's uses a cleaner approach:

```
@echo off
set pingIP=8.8.8.8

:doPing
cls
echo Pinging %pingIP%
ping -n 3 -w 100 %pingIP% > nul
set result=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %result%==1 (call :failure) ELSE (call :success)
goto :doPing

:success
Echo The internet is working at the moment. 
Echo You can close out of the console window now, or let it run a little longer to be absolutely sure.
set /p response=Stop monitoring? (Y/N)
if /i "%response%"=="y" (exit) else (goto :eof)

:failure
Echo The internet is not working at the moment.
set /p response=Stop monitoring? (Y/N)
if /i "%response%"=="y" (exit) else (goto :eof)
```

Comment: The :GOOD tag does too, though, yet it works as intended. 
They're like that on purpose. I wanted the script to continue once the user hit OK or the message box timed out. 

I'll try removing goto nonetheless, to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Alright, ran into a new issue. I turned my Wi-Fi off, removed the last goto statement, and tested the script, and it gave me a "Working" result. I removed the _@echo off_ to see where it went wrong, and turns out that some failed pings are returning ErrorValues of 0. How/Why is that happening, in your opinion?

Comment: Sorry, I just pointed out the most obvious issue in my mind, but there's one even more obvious: whenever you test the ERRORLEVEL value, you have to do it in reverse order. So check for the 1 value first, then for the 0 value. Actually, the entire script could (should?) be rewritten. Do you _really_ need to keep it working in a loop as it does now? Or do you want it to exit at some point? Because the wayt it's set now, it'll run forever...

Comment: Just added my own version of the same script in my original answer, in case you want to try it.

Comment: That didn't fix it either. I believe the issue was the inconsistent/inaccurate ping errorlevel results ("0" when it should be "1" and vice-versa). I fixed that by specifically checking for the presence of latency values in the result instead. Also, yeah, kinda, I wanted the script to run constantly, because this was to be part of another script I'm working on (which I've finished now), that runs in the background and checks for connectivity, and "fixes" it whenever it's down, because I use my PC to stream data constantly, and can't be in front of it 24x7 to catch downtimes.

Comment: Your script is definitely far cleaner, by the way. That was kind of you, that you worked on one :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @Filipus with some colors ;)

```
@echo off
Title Check Internet Connexion
Mode Con Cols=60 lines=10
set pingIP=8.8.8.8
Call:init
:doPing
cls
Call:Color 0E "Pinging..... %pingIP%" 1
echo(
ping -n 3 -w 100 %pingIP% > nul
set result=%ERRORLEVEL%
if '%result%' EQU '1' (call :failure) ELSE (call :success)
goto :doPing

:success
Call:Color 0A "The internet is working at the moment." 1 
Call:Color 0A "You can close out of the console window now," 1
Call:Color 0A "Or let it run a little longer to be absolutely sure." 1
echo(
set /p response=Stop monitoring? (Y/N)
if /i "%response%"=="y" (exit) else (goto :eof)

:failure
cls
echo(
Call:Color 0C "The internet is not working at the moment." 1
timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul
goto :doPing


:init
prompt $g
for /F "delims=." %%a in ('"prompt $H. & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"
exit /b

:color
set nL=%3
if not defined nL echo requires third argument & pause > nul & goto :eof
if %3 == 0 (
    <nul set /p ".=%bs%">%2 & findstr /v /a:%1 /r "^$" %2 nul & del %2 2>&1 & goto :eof
) else if %3 == 1 (
    echo %bs%>%2 & findstr /v /a:%1 /r "^$" %2 nul & del %2 2>&1 & goto :eof
)
exit /b
```